# Text moves down when using mouseover to show a span

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey i have created a HTML file which is showing a span onmouseover with java script but the text which is under it is going down. I don't know how can i solve this problem.Please Help me Here is My Code with HTML,CSS and some javascript

```
<html><body><style>.Category{
background-color: rgb(77, 178, 236);
padding: 8px 12px;
width:10px;
height:500px;
margin:4px;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
color: white !important;
z-index: 1;
}
.fblike
{
display: none;
position:relative;
top:-25px;
right:-600px;
width:20px;
}</style>
<div id="content"><div id="content1" onmouseover="document.getElementById('fblike').style.display = 'block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('fblike').style.display = '';"><span class="Category">How TO</span> <span id="fblike" class="fblike">Utkarsh</span><br><br><div class="image">Utkarsh</div></div><hr>
</body></html>
```

Comment: If you `position:absolute;` your `.fblike` it won't disrupt flow of the other elements. Because it's `position:relative;` it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to position the `.fblike` class as absolute and then modify the top and right properties in the css to suit.

I have shown this here: http://jsfiddle.net/drfjy/

Answer (score 1):

If you `position:absolute;` your `.fblike` it won't disrupt flow of the other elements. Because it's `position:relative;` it will.

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/A6afY/

```
.Category{
background-color: rgb(77, 178, 236);
padding: 8px 12px;
width:10px;
height:500px;
margin:4px;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',sans-serif;
color: white !important;
z-index: 1;
}
.fblike
{
display: none;
position:absolute;

    /* commented so easier to show the fix
top:-25px;
right:-600px; */
width:20px;
}


#content1 {
    /* absolute positioned elements must have positioned parents */
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use id `#fblike` instead class `.fblike` ,and change position  `absolute` and set the `top` and `left` edge.

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/LUz9D/)**

```
#fblike
{
display: none;
position: absolute;
width: 20px;
top: 5px;
left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying style.display which won't consume space when the value is set to none.
If it is set to block the space will be consumed and it will be displayed.

You can try style.visibility for achieving what you need.